# Read page source from current chrome/firefox browser session

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, firefox

So I'm trying to read the current tabs page source from chrome and/or firefox current browser session via 3rd application ie using c#.

a similar, if not the same question has been asked previously here -

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871640/how-to-read-html-source-from-opened-google-chrome-or-firefox
```

but it wasn't answered.

I know i could recreate the request by obtaining the url and using httpwebrequests or something similar, however I want to do it simultaneously through reading the browsers current state.

I'm basically asking what approach to take, so in regards to providing attempts/code I couldn't as I don't know where to begin with even attempting to retrieve page source from a browsers current state.

I know this is possible as I assume malwarebytes and other anti viruses do something similar, as if you visit a page that is blacklisted for malware, it either redirects you to a safepage, telling you this site is malicious or it injects html into the current page with a warning alertbox to prevent further usage.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, applications like MalwareBytes and similar software intercept the http request on the network, they do not spy on the contents of the browser directly, unless you install addons / extensions allowing them to do so. The browser makes a request, this is intercepted and instead of forwarding it to the server to provide a response, the software provides you with its own response; or it forwards the request, receives and checks the response and warns you if it finds issues with the response before handing it back to the browser.

Comment: @Grismar thank you for that info, I can definitely take that approach and it would be just as effective, however how would I then feed back data to the browser, for example - inject html or js? or simply redirect the user to a safepage? similar to what malwarebytes performs if they deem site as malicious

Comment: If you can intercept a request, you can also provide an alternative response, or inject whatever you need into the response as it comes back from the actual server. Note that this requires a lot of trust from the user for your software - you'd be able to see all the requests and responses going back and forth. The response you provide can also be or include a redirection of course.